# How can I add text to the end of a line that contains multiple strings?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a file like this:

```
1;1471375551;joe;WO12344;
2;1471378551;frank;WO12345;1471380211
3;1471383211;frank;WO12345;1471385211
4;1471385311;frank;WO12345;
5;1471385311;joe;WO12346;1471388211
```

I'd like to use a bash script to find the line that contains a specified name (like `frank`) as well as a specified WO number (like `WO12345`) and also ends with a `;`, then add a string to the end of the line.  I want to edit the file directly, not output to stdout.  I know how to use `read` to get the name and WO number. I'm guessing `sed` with `-i` is the right tool.  How can I do that?

Comment: Your example is confusing me.  Please show us a before and after example.  Ideally you should show us what you tried that didn't work as this is not a script writing service (even if the question is simple).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the name and WO are always consecutive, it's quite straightforward:

```
sed  '/frank;WO12345;/s/;$/;sometext/' -i file
```

If they can appear either way around, or not necessarily next to each other, use blocks of commands to combine the two tests:

```
sed  '/;frank;/{/;WO12345;/s/;$/;sometext/}' -i file
```

Comment: Thanks, that works.  Will this rewrite the entire file?  If I can, I'd like to only write `sometext` because my file might be pretty big.

Comment: @aswine What do you mean by "only write `sometext`"?  It's inserting text; everything after it will now be a bit later in the file.  It *might* depend on your filesystem, but whatever method you pick, you will probably be rewriting the whole file from that point all the way to the end.

Comment: @aswine `sed -i` will just write to a temporary file then, when it's done, move that temporary file over the original. There aren't many ways around this no matter what tool you use.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is better suited for field separated data.

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F';' '$3=="frank" && $4="WO12345" {print $0 ";Foobar"}' OFS=';' file.txt
```

replace `;Foobar` with what you want to insert at the end.

Here we are checking if `;` separated 3rd and 4th fields match out desired strings, if so string `;Foobar` is added at the end.

Latest GNU `awk` (>=4.10) has inplace editing option:

```
awk -i inplace -F';' '$3=="frank" && $4="WO12345" {print $0 ";Foobar"}' OFS=';' file.txt
```

If you don't have that use `sponge` from GNU `moreutils` or a temporaruy file:

```
awk -F';' '$3=="frank" && $4="WO12345" {print $0 ";Foobar"}' OFS=';' file.txt | sponge file.txt

awk -F';' '$3=="frank" && $4="WO12345" {print $0 ";Foobar"}' OFS=';' \
       file.txt >file_temp.txt && mv file_temp.txt file.txt
```

---

If you insist on `sed`:

```
sed -Ei '/^([^;]*;){2}frank;WO12345;/ s/$/;Foobar/' file.txt
```

- `([^;]*;){2}` matches first two fields and then we have checked if the 3rd and fourth fields are desired and then the replacement is done

---

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt
1;1471375551;joe;WO12344;
2;1471378551;frank;WO12345;1471380211
3;1471383211;frank;WO12345;1471385211
4;1471385311;frank;WO12345;
5;1471385311;joe;WO12346;1471388211

$ awk -F';' '$3=="frank" && $4="WO12345" {print $0 ";Foobar"}' OFS=';' file.txt
2;1471378551;frank;WO12345;1471380211;Foobar
3;1471383211;frank;WO12345;1471385211;Foobar
4;1471385311;frank;WO12345;;Foobar

$ sed -E '/^([^;]*;){2}frank;WO12345;/ s/$/;Foobar/' file.txt
1;1471375551;joe;WO12344;
2;1471378551;frank;WO12345;1471380211;Foobar
3;1471383211;frank;WO12345;1471385211;Foobar
4;1471385311;frank;WO12345;;Foobar
5;1471385311;joe;WO12346;1471388211
```